# Values of cohomology theory on a point

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, motives, motivic-cohomology

$\DeclareMathOperator\Sm{Sm}$It is a well-known fact that in algebraic topology, generalized cohomology theories are determined by their values on the point. I was wondering whether anything similar to that is or expected to be true in algebraic geometry? More precisely I had the following question in my mind:

- For a Bloch-Ogus cohomology theory on the category $\Sm_k$ of smooth $k$-schemes with the big Zariski site, if we know that cohomologies of $\text{Spec}(k)$ at all dimensions and weights are trivial, does it imply that the cohomology theory is trivial?

Bloch-Ogus cohomology theory is a functor from $\Sm_k$ to abelian groups that has two grading $h^i(X,j)$ similar to the motivic cohomology. These functors are supposed to satisfy certain properties like homotopy invariance, purity, transfer under finite maps and maybe some other extra properties (like Poincaré duality).

Edit: Here is the standard reference for Bloch-Ogus: [Spencer Bloch, Arthur Ogus, Gersten’s conjecture and the homology of schemes](http://www.numdam.org/article/ASENS_1974_4_7_2_181_0.pdf)
There is slightly different version called Bloch-Ogus-Gabber and the reference for that is: J Colliot-Thelene, Raymond Hoobler and Bruno Kahn – The Bloch-Ogus-Gabber theorem.

- Motivation: So I wanted to add why I suddenly thought something like this (it might require some modifications) might be true. A lot of big open conjectures in algebraic geometry like Tate's conjecture, Suslin's conjecture (which implies standard conjectures) and the Bloch-Kato conjecture (which is a theorem) can be reformulated as vanishing of a certain Bloch-Ogus cohomology theory. But of course I am not sure whether being a Bloch-Ogus cohomology theory and the fact it vanishes on the base field is all you need.

Comment: Could you provide a reference for Bloch-Ogus?

Comment: To determine a cohomology theory on smooth varieties you should also fix its values on ("twists" of  spectra of) all function field. Hence the answer to your question should be negative. However, you can be interested in Vishik's free theories; see https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.04703

Comment: @MikhailBondarko Thanks. The paper you've referenced does not work with bigraded cohomology theory like the Bloch-Ogus one. But is there any way to turn the bigraded Bloch-Ogus to the cohomology theory mentioned in the paper? Regarding the function fields, in order to prove a bloch-ogus cohomology theory is trivial it suffices to show triviality on the function fields and even it is enough to show triviality on the function fields of rational varieties. You are claiming that this is an additional data. Is there a reason why this data has to be additional?

Comment: You may say that there are "lots of independent motives", and you have to determine the values of your theory on all of them to fix your theory. I can probably formalize this argument somehow; yet at the moment I don't know how to construct plenty of cohomology theories that satisfy all axioms of Bloch and Ogus.

Comment: I don't think your first statement is true in general. I believe there can be different generalized cohomology theories that have the same values for a point. However, the statement is true when the cohomology of a point is nontrivial only in one dimension by Eilenberg-Steenrod.

Comment: @GregFriedman You are right, what I had on my mind was if it is trivial on the point the whole cohomology theory is trivial.

Comment: @MikhailBondarko So you imply that Bloch-Ogus is more restrictive than Levine-Morel plus Vishik's localization property? Could you say in which way?

Comment: As far as I remember,  one just needs more data for a Bloch-Ogus theory.

Comment: You have to be careful with the statement `determined by their values on a point': compare $K^*(X)$ with $\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} H^{2n+*}(X)$.  The existence of non-trivial differentials in the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence shows that these two generalized cohomology theories are not equal, although additively they take the same value on a point.  (I didn't see Greg Friedman's comment until after I had written this: I suppose I'm giving an example of what he explains.)